# Is it possible for program to crash even with try/except statement that captures Exception in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am creating some automation that restarts a device at a certain point. In order to reconnect after it reboots, I want to continue to attempt to connect after a wait period until it finally reconnects. Since there will be errors when it fails to reconnect, I thought I could catch all exceptions and then just sleep for some time period and then run the connection code again and continue this loop. However, my program still crashes after it reaches the connection errors. Are there just some exceptions that can not be caught?

This is the function I created for reference and I am still just getting a bunch of different errors like `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`, `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError`, `urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError`, and `ConnectionRefusedError`

```
def establish_session(device):
    try:
        sess = IdentityServicesEngineAPI(username=config.username,
                                    password=config.password,
                                    base_url='https://' + device,
                                    verify=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print("connection refused. node rebooting. Trying again in 60 seconds")
        time.sleep(60)
        return establish_session(device) # Nested here...

    return sess
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Update: adding full traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 403, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1053, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 363, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x104e2b670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='device1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/task (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x104e2b670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/ciscoisesdk/restsession.py", line 497, in request
    response = self._req_session.request(method, abs_url, **kwargs)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='device1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/task (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x104e2b670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 403, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1053, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 363, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x104e29930>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='device1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/task (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x104e29930>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ciscoisesdk/restsession.py", line 504, in request
    response = self._req_session.request(method, abs_url,
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='device1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/task (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x104e29930>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Pre_Post_Checks_Automation/test_api_calls.py", line 5, in <module>
    hold = api.tasks.get_task_status().response
  File "python3.10/site-packages/ciscoisesdk/api/v3_1_patch_1/tasks.py", line 123, in get_task_status
    _api_response = self._session.get(endpoint_full_url, params=_params)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/ciscoisesdk/restsession.py", line 609, in get
    response = self.request('GET', url, erc, 0, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "python3.10/site-packages/ciscoisesdk/restsession.py", line 507, in request
    raise ciscoisesdkException('Socket error {}'.format(e))
ciscoisesdk.exceptions.ciscoisesdkException: Socket error HTTPSConnectionPool(host='device1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/task (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x104e29930>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

Comment: On a different note, you are calling `establish_session(device)` recursively, which is using the stack for no reason. Then, if a retry *does* succeed, and you `return sess`, then that variable will be lost. You meant to write: `return establish_session(device) # Nested here...`

Comment: can you post your actual traceback?

Comment: @quamrana Ah yeah I see that. thank you. That honestly might fix it all since the rest of the program will be able to use the connection. Will update post shortly

Comment: `establish_session` isn't actually in that traceback. It sounds like your exception is happening somewhere else.

Comment: @user2357112 I totally overlooked that. I tried looking through all the of the other files it mentions and they all seemed to raise their own exceptions so I assumed mine would catch it but I will look closer cause you are right, it doesn't appear.

Comment: You have to settle on one question. It seems like your error tracebacks are a distraction. Please pick a question about the code you posted or the tracebacks.

Comment: On a completely different note, to answer the question in the title, yes, some exceptions are not `Exception`. For example, `GeneratorExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` are not subclasses of `Exception` but of `BaseException`, meaning they won't be caught in the `except Exception` clause.

Comment: @quamrana Yeah, i did not plan on adding the traceback. Was more just curious about if there were other kinds. Appreciate your help with the recursive thing tho. Thanks

Comment: @juanpethes Answered my question. Not sure how to close this question and mark as read since it is in a comment. Sorry, new to all this.

Comment: Sure! Glad it helped. I will add it as an actual answer not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, yes, some exceptions are not `Exception`. For example, `GeneratorExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` are not subclasses of `Exception` but of `BaseException`, meaning they won't be caught in the `except Exception` clause.

See this for a hierarchy of builtin exceptions:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

as well as this very useful video from mCoding:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrVfY9SuO64